# WooCommerce REST API Edit Customer Downloads

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

The REST API v2 customers downloads endpoint at:

/wp-json/wc/v2/customers//downloads

is currently read-only. We need the ability to edit the 'Downloads remaining' and 'Access expires' values for individual customer downloads and cannot currently do this via the REST API.

Anyone know another way to edit these values without having to use the WooCommerce Admin page to change these one by one?